# Libgdx how to set initial starting point of Bezier curve

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, bezier

I am managing to draw a sprite along a bezier curve, much to my delight. However I cannot get it to initialize from a starting point of my definition, no matter what I have tried it will always begin the bezier from the position 0,0.

This is my bezier:

```
final Vector2 tmpV = new Vector2();

paths.add(new Bezier<Vector2>(new Vector2(w, 150), new Vector2(w, h),
                new Vector2(0, 0)));
```

and this is where I am effectively telling the sprite to follow the Bezier:

```
position.add(tmpV).scl(t).cpy();
```

I am aware the Bezier values look a little weird, that's just me trying to make sense of them and, to be honest it isn't even drawing the path I want. The path I ewould like to draw would begin in the top right corner, arch down to the bottom left and return back to the top right.

Comment: How is the code you're using to tell "the sprite to follow the bezier" related to the path you apparently created. Perhaps have a look at sscce.org

Comment: this looks like a quadratic curve, based on the fact that you're giving it only 3 coordinates. If so: you can't make the path you want with just one of those. You need at least two of them, and it'd be a jarringly fast departure and arrival from/at the starting point